# Change color of actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have looked through the Android examples online and perused through all the available documentation, but am still befuddled. I am targeting version 19 of the Android SDK as minSDK. All I need to do is to change the background color of the actionbar. My code for some reason does not seem to work.

1. I want the window background color of the rest of the app to be white.
2. I want the background of the actionbar to be blue.

Below is my resources file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/post_action_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="post_action_bar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This does not work. The rest of the app is white, but my bar has a grayish color.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set programatically in code like

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
```

Comment: I want to set it through the xml not the code

Answer (score 2):

It's as easy as adding this to your AppTheme

```
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
```

Note: this will work pre-lolipop as long as your theme's parent is from `Theme.AppCompat` and your support library is atleast v21, so if you havent already update the support lib to the latest which at this time is v23.0.1 (i think)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Read [this](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) if you want to learn more about styling your ActionBar, and more

Comment: colorPrimary is supported in v21 not 19

Comment: @OlivierTwist Did you read through the link in the answer? Let me just quote this "On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets."

Comment: That means as long as your theme's parent is from Theme.AppCompat, it will work pre-v21

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Here you have everything explained in detail about styling the Action Bar.

Best regards

Comment: I tried just what is said in the link - I believe. Look at my resource code.